# Blank Emulator In Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

After fixing [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29872225/950427), my app compiles fine. When I run it in the emulator the screen is black and nothing loads into the interface.

Please see Android Manifest below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appname.android"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.0.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" >
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.appname.android.ui.<namehere>"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.appname.android.ui.<namehere>"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:label="@string/<namehere>"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.appname.android.ui.<namehere>"
            android:label="@string/<namehere>"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.appname.android.ui.<namehere>"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/<namehere>" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.appname.android.ui.<namehere>"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:label="@string/<namehere>" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.appname.android.ui.<namehere>"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:label="@string/<namehere>" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.appname.android.ui.<namehere>"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:label="@string/<namehere>" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You said in the previous question that you got the application from somewhere? What is in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and `MainActivity.java`? Does it `timeout`? An Android `ANR`?

Comment: Post your MainActivity file

Comment: @JaredBurrows Please see AndroidManifest.xml above. Not sure where to find MainActivity.java. I couldn't find it in the solution. Not sure if it timeouts, because the emulator opens but never does anything. Doesnt even load the OS. Please advise, you are a life saver!

Comment: Why did you rename all the classes? The "MainActivity" is the one with the `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`. Wha do you mean the OS does not load?

Comment: Renamed the classes because I don't want to disclose the project name or functionality in detail to the Web. Not sure my bosses stance on how much he wants the world to know about. The OS does not load on the Emulator. Just opens up and is blacked out.

Comment: If I open the Emulator right from the AVD it does the same thing so maybe not related to the app itself?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking. I created the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894512/blank-emulator-opening-in-avd I have not had the time to try any of the suggestions yet.