# Blank Emulator Opening In AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application, android-sdk-tools, android-virtual-device

When I launch the `emulator` manually from `AVD` I just get a blank screen. `Android` never loads on it. I tried all the different settings in `AVD`. I also let the `emulator` stay open for hours to make sure it wasn't just really slow. Please help!

Comment: did u downloaded complete ARM images of sdk of any android versions?

Comment: did you get some error in the log?

Comment: Share your system config

Comment: try to use genymotion or bluestack

Comment: post you emulator configuration..