# Android Proguard ZipException while generating signed APK

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

My project structure is as follows:

-app/ (main module)

-module1/ (dependency for app/)

-module2/ (dependency for module1/)

After setting minifyenabled as true and while generating signed APK, I get the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>   work connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Any normal debug or release build without minifyenabled goes fine. I have already tried removing dependency and re-adding as well as re-sync, but to no respite.
Any idea as to why does this happen? I am using android studio and gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872225/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry)

Comment: what jars and dependencies are you using? can you list them out?

Comment: Issue was with proguard configs. Not really a duplicate of the question mentioned in comment. Issue was wrong usage of -keep directives in proguard