# duplicate Entry com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat.class

Tags: android, android-studio, duplicates, android-gradle-plugin, zxing

When I am running the app on Android 6.0 and above directly through run from android studio then able to run the app successfully. But when creating a build through build apk from android studio then I am getting following error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat.class**
```

Below is my gradle file :

```
dependencies {
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.11.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: share your `Build.gradle` with question

Comment: @NileshRathod added gradle code in question, please check

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude "com.google.zxing" module "core"

```
implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:{VERSION}') {
    exclude group: "com.google.zxing", module: 'core'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use same version depedency of `firebase`

**use this**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
```

**instead of this**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
```

Comment: I did the same as you said but nothing is changed

Comment: @Shanky check out this few links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872225/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry

Comment: @Shanky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139682/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-com-google-zxing-barcodeformat-clas

Answer (score 0):

You might be having same file named as `BarcodeFormat.java` in your project. Please rename it to anything else and see if the error gets solved.