# TransformException for duplicate class entry

Tags: java, android, gradle, chromecast

I got "`Error converting bytecode to dex`" in a Chromecast project with Remote Display API. I solved this by adding "`multiDexEnabled true`", but this only generated another error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.>
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/internal/zzlg.class

I have checked my `Gradle` files, but I can not find any conflict.  I read other similar threads and tried their code fixes, but no use here. How can I proceed with this?These are my gradle files:

[Gradle files](http://www.mobile-visuals.com/gradle1.txt)

Answer (score 2):

First, try to clean/rebuild the project because usually that kind of error will be gone after you clean/rebuild the project.

From this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html), when you add `multiDexEnabled true` in the gradle.files, make sure you also add compile `'com.android.support:multidex:x.x.x'` in the dependencies.

For more information, check these related SO questions:

- [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)
- [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872225/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry)

Answer (score 0):

You may be compiling the same dependency multiple times. For example, `play-services-cast` depends on `appcompat-v7`. You can prevent recompiling the same dependency with:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.+')
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Use the shell command `gradlew -q YourApp:dependencies` to print your app's dependency graph; then in your `build.gradle`, exclude dependencies that show up multiple times.